# Adding today extension project reference to iOS App

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add a today widget to my Xamarin iOS app and when I try to add it as a reference I get this error:

> a reference to could not be added. adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency`

I am running VS 2015 update 2 and the stable version of Xamarin

Any help would be amazing, Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: No I created a iOS project then added a today extension to the project and now i'm trying make the today extension work by adding the today extension as a reference to the iOS project

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your iOS App project will have a reference to your Today Extension Project. You don't need a reference from the Today Extension to the App project as you interact with the extension like this from your App project:

```
var controller = NCWidgetController.GetWidgetController ();
controller.SetHasContent (true, "<your today extensions bundle id>");
```

You references should look like this:
[image]

Have a look at how this [sample code](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/ios8/ExtensionsDemo) for a Today extension is put together. [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/extensions/today_widget/) on extension project